# How to make certain months unselectable with datepicker?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I would like to make certain months unselectable. So for example the user should be able to navigate different years, but 'November' will always be greyed-out (or even better, completely excluded from the widget).

Right now, I have tried something like this:

https://jsfiddle.net/4btvnx36/1/

**html**

```
<input type="text" id="datepicker" />
```

**js**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#datepicker').datepicker({
        beforeShowMonth: function (date) {
        if (date.getMonth() == 10) {
            return [false];
        }
      }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The jQueryUI datepicker does not have a `beforeShowMonth` property, only `beforeShowDay`. You also need to return `[true]` from that function if the date is valid. With that in mind, try this:

```
$('#datepicker').datepicker({
    beforeShowDay: function(date) {
        return [date.getMonth() != 10];
    }
});
```

[**Updated fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/4btvnx36/2/)

Comment: You are very quick sir. :)

Comment: Do you think there is any easy way to completely remove the month? Not something I absolutely need, but I am making a menu for commencement dates and it would be much more usable if I could keep only the ones I need.

Comment: I don't believe you can do that in the jQuery Datepicker control. It would be confusing for your user's even if you could as they would expect to cycle through all months, not click right three times from January and be in December all of a sudden, for example

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I am actually using the [boostrap datepicker](http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) with `minViewMode='years'`, which shows a list of months. But maybe I should open another post to present this new issue.